# Do someone know any good USB PHP server which support debugging?

Tags: php, debugging

I am doing php work through http://www.usbwebserver.net/en/ and using it with phpstorm. When I try to debug I have seen that Dll could not be loaded PHP_curl so  I can't debug my code.

Do someone know any kind of trick as we have for .net in VWD. I means just put breakpoint and it's hit when browser make request.

Do someone know any good usb server for PHP that support debugging. If something more I want then I want to know how I can debug it like people debug their asp.net apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot "step" through your code in PHP. Using strict error reporting will help.

When it comes to CURL you can also use [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to see what some potential 'fatal' problems are occurring.